# Parent child relation between Post and Page

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a recipes website called [Green Comfort Food](http://www.greencomfortfood.com). I'm new to building websites so I am figuring it out with not a lot of background knowledge.

I have a homepage, recipes page, pages to devide those recipes like a lunch page, diner page etc and finally I have the post with the actual recipe. I use elemontor to show the blog grid on these lunch, diner etc pages. So the structure should be home > Recipes > lunch > post.

It is easy to create a parent child relation between the different pages but since I made the recipes as a post there is no child parent relation anymore. So now its Home > recipes > lunch and then its home > post.

I would like to fix it by using custom post types but for some reason this doesn't allow me to use elemontor. I tried to make the pages to posts and create the hierarchy by catogories but the the breadcrumbs will link me to the archive page for the posts which I cant seem to change.

Can anyone help me with this? The main thing is to get my structure right and preferably use breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom Post Type for Recipes and create custom taxonomy [i.e. Pies and Pastries, Breakfast & Lunch etc.] and then create new posts under it.

Then you can make it like this, Home -> Categories -> Sub-Categories [if available] -> Post and url can be https://domain.tld/recipes/lunch/post-name or https://domain.tld/recipes/lunch/dessert/post-name/

** domain.tld will be replace with your host url.